# Защита от телепортации в MMORPG Игре

Tags: php, разработка-игр

Такая вот беда, клепаю ммо игрушку. И вот возник такой вопросик. В игре есть локации, ну например:

```
 /game.php?page=map_1 
 /game.php?page=map_2 
 /game.php?page=map_3
```

И хотелось, чтоб пользователи не могли просто ввести их адрес и перенестись, и я написал такую штуку:

```
if ($_SESSION['username']) {
    include 'conect_db.php';
    $block = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if (strlen($block) > 0) {
        /* Выводим локацию */

    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Ай-ай-ай Не моно так делать');</script>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Пройдите авторизацию');</script>";
}
```

И, вуаля, когда он просто вводит адрес, пользователю выводит сообщение: **Ай-ай-ай Не моно так делать**. Но вдруг, я открыл Оперу, рассадник лагов, открываю исходный код и ввожу:

```
<script>location.href='/game.php?page=map_3';</script>
```

Тыкаю применить и меня переносит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заклеить эту дыру?

Comment: @oOKomarOo, это не Опера рассадник лагов, а ваш код.

Comment: Может и так, учусь просто еще)

Comment: @oOKomarOo, я уже писал вам в другом вопросе, что вот эта защита абсолютно бредовая.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделай права пользователям. и по этому флагу проверяй может он увидеть мап_3 или мап_2. если да то показываешь если нет то не показываешь. иначе вряд ли справишься с задачей.

Comment: ага)) Вот оно чё, ладно, понял)) Спс))

Comment: @Shrek, вы не понял вопроса.  
В данном случае нужна карта локаций.

Comment: 2 @Construct по-русски пишем правильно. и вообще-то ответ правильный, читать нужно и понимать вопросы.

Comment: @Construct, все ведь поняли, что это была опечатка?  
Нет, это вы не поняли вопроса.

Answer (score 4):

Опера тут действительно ни при чем. Храните положение игрока не в адресной строке ($_GET), а в БД ($_POST). Как следствие, пользователь будет видеть адрес вида */game.php* без get-параметров.

Comment: И это тоже не защита.

Answer (score 3):

Тут нужна карта локаций. К примеру, типа такого:

```
array(  
0 => array('moves' => array(1,2), 'name' => 'Одна локация'),  
1 => array('moves' => array(0,3,4), 'name' => 'Другая локация')  
);
```

таким образом, есть две локи, с данными именами, из 0-вой можно пойти в 1 и 2, из первой в 0, 3 и 4. При попытке перехода между локами нужно проверять по карте локаций, возможен ли такой переход. Права пользователей тут ни при чём, разве если только не хотите сделать более сложную структуру, к примеру, игроки только определённой фракции могут входить в данную локацию. Тогда уже надо усложнить структуру массива.

Comment: Можете это подробнее рассказать? Как сделать карту локации?

Comment: Тут фишка в том что у тебя где-то(например в переменной сессии) записано текущее местоположение игрока и когда игрок запрашивает новую локацию ты проверяешь с помощью карты локации(в данном случае у @Construct это массив ассоциативных массивов, !но это только пример) может ли он с текущей локации переместится в ту которую он захотел. Если взять пример @Construct, то если игрок находится в локации 0, то он может перейти только в локации 1 и 2, если в локации 1, то только в локации 0, 3 и 4.